# Unable to Clear Cache in Wordpress using wp_cache_flush()

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, plugins

I am currently working on a Plugin for Pressable and wanted to Clear the WP Cache, But when i try to run wp_cache_flush(), this function returns NULL instead of a TRUE or FALSE. I have also Included the wp-load.php

A brief intro to Pressable Hosting. this Hosting Provider has Wordpress Installation in a Folder that is a Symlink and I am not able to access that, Also, the wp-load.php is also a symlink. We are only provided with wp-content folder.

Feel free to ask if you face any difficulty while understanding the problem.

PHP script is this:

```
    <?php

    require("./wp-load.php");
    global $bvRespArray;
    $bvRespArray = array("signature" => "blogVault API");

    function bvStatusAdd($key, $value) {
        global $bvRespArray;
        $bvRespArray[$key] = $value;
    }

    function bvAutoStatusExit() {
        global $bvRespArray;
        die("bvbvbvbvbv".serialize($bvRespArray)."bvbvbvbvbv");
    }

    if (wp_cache_flush())
        bvStatusAdd("success", true);
    else
        bvStatusAdd("error", true);

    bvAutoStatusExit();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with Pressable Servers. The Pressable has Configured their WP installations in their own Format. The Default Wordpress wp_cache_flush() function return BOOL i.e. true or false depending upon Success or Failure resp.

But the Pressable has changed this definition to return NULL each time whether the Function is Failed or Succeed. So, to change this workflow i created a custom function Like this:-

```
function myCacheClear() {
   wp_cache_clear();
   return true;
}
```

now the function can be used as:-

```
if(myCacheClear())
  do_this;
else
   do_this;
```

Hope this might help someone facing Problem like Me.

-Happy Coding

Comment: I believe you meant  wp_cache_flush() instead of wp_cache_clear().